# How do I properly sync up local Alexa skills development with the remote Alexa model using ask-cli?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I've cloned a skill to my local machine, did some work and deployed it. That works fine.

The issue I'm facing is, if i've made changes(ie deleted an intent) on the remote interaction model and cloned(ask clone) the model again the local version shows both the old model (deleted) code and the new updated model code. I'm new to skills development and only recently got into using the ask-cli. I might be using the wrong command to run on the cli idk. Could you let me know if there is a right command to sync up both model correctly?

I have tried using `ask diff`but it doesn't show any changes apart from the version number.

I have also used `ask clone` to overwrite it but it doesn't update the code correctly.

```
======================= VERSION DIFF RESULT =======================
Your version of skill.json is up to date.

Your models/en-GB.json is based on the latest version. Please see 
the content diff for your new changes.

Your version of Lambda function is up to date.

No in-skill product for the current skill.

======================= CONTENT DIFF RESULT =======================
===================================================================
--- local models/en-GB.json
+++ remote models/en-GB.json
@@ -672,6 +672,6 @@
         ]
       }
     ]
   },
-  "version": "37"
-}
+  "version": "38"
+}
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: I'm also hoping to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the way to do this is to run:

```
ask api head-model -s [SKILL_ID] -l en-US
```

This will output:

```
ETag: [ETAG_VALUE]
```

You then copy `ETAG_VALUE` and place it in your `.ask/config` file:

```
"interactionModel": {
  "en-US": {
    "eTag": "[ETAG_VALUE]"
  }
},
```

Wish there was a much simpler way to do this, like `ask sync`